# GraphQL: Não consigo parar a execução do Node e retornar o Erro (Erro de Negócio)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, graphql

Estou tentando criar umas queries e mutations, no Node com GraphQL. Já procurei como resolver o problema e não acho uma solução. Será que alguém conseguiria me ajudar?

No projeto coloquei as dependências graphql-yoga e mongoose.

Estou montando uma Mutation que "saca" dinheiro de uma "conta". Consigo fazer executar, diminuindo o valor do saldo no banco de dados. O problema é quando tenta sacar valor maior do que o saldo em conta. Precisava que nesse momento exibisse erro de que não tem saldo suficiente.

A Aplicação apenas está exibindo saldo NULL, e não exibe a mensagem do erro. Sabem como incluir no retorno da Mutation??

Todo o resto está funcionando.

Abaixo o código do arquivo resolvers.js (na mutation sacar, após itentificar o erro de saldo insuficiente, gero o erro, a aplicação sai do fluxo e entra no catch. Porém não sei como logar para a response a mensagem de erro. Joguei apenas no console.

```
const Conta = require("./Conta");
let newSaldo;

module.exports = {
  Query: {
    contas: () => Conta.find(),
    conta: (root, { numero }) => Conta.findOne({ numero }),
  },

  Mutation: {
    createConta: (root, { numero, saldo, cliente }) => Conta.create({ numero, saldo, cliente }),

    depositar: (root, { numero, valor }) => Conta.findOne({numero})
                                            .then(() => Conta.updateOne({numero},{$inc:{saldo : valor}}))
                                            .then(() => Conta.findOne({numero})),

    sacar: (root, { numero, valor }) => Conta.findOne({numero})
                                        .then(value => {
                                            newSaldo = value.saldo
                                            if (valor > value.saldo) {
                                                throw new Error("Saldo Insuficiente")
                                            }
                                            else{
                                                newSaldo = value.saldo - valor
                                            }
                                        }) 
                                        .then(() => Conta.updateOne({numero},{$set:{saldo: newSaldo}}))
                                        .then(() => Conta.findOne({numero}))
                                        .catch((err) => console.log(err))                  
  },
}
```

Arquivo schema.graphql

```
type Conta {
  id: ID!
  numero: String!
  saldo: Float!
  cliente: String!
}

type Query {
  contas: [Conta!]
  conta(numero: Int!): Conta
}

type Mutation {
  createConta(numero: Int!, saldo: Float!, cliente: String!): Conta
  depositar(numero: Int!, valor: Float!): Conta
  sacar(numero: Int!, valor: Float!): Conta
}
```

Abaixo a execução da Mutation, com retorno, para uma conta que não tem saldo suficiente. Exibindo Saldo NULL. Preciso nessa tela retornar a mensagem do erro. Conseguem ajudar??

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentou criar uma `Promise` e retornar ela no resolver? Não sei se o `Promise.reject` vai ter efeito dentro do `then`

Comment: Algo [assim](https://gist.github.com/denisrudnei/c5bbe4308263e84ec2781de8f5fc893d)

Comment: Adicionando, abaixo da linha do promisse.reject, um catch, parei de receber o erro do Node (UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning). Porém ainda não sei como jogar esse erro pro retorno da Mutation.Vou atualizar o código na pergunta

Comment: Com isso tu impede que o erro seja propagado para o resolver

Comment: Então como devo tratar? Alguma idéia? Eu gero o erro de negocio, porém nunca consigo exibir no retorno.

Comment: Eu sempre retorno a promise pro resolver, se der erro o mesmo mostra que falhou, em caso de sucesso ele traz os dados

Comment: Eu criei  erro, porém é um erro de negocio. Então não exibe erro, me exibe o saldo da conta. Preciso que exiba um erro/mensagem de saldo insuficiente

Comment: Consegui criar um erro que tira do resto do fluxo. Porém exibe resposta com saldo NULL, preciso que exiba a mensagem de erro. Como consigo fazer isso no catch???  Alterei o corpo da minha pergunta com novo codigo

Comment: Fiz [dessa](https://gitlab.com/denisrudnei/439612) forma, só deixei o erro subir, não acredito que tenha como retornar o erro, como se fosse o resultado da consulta em si, ela vai retornar um valor nulo, já que não há o que retornar, o erro vem separado. [Aqui](https://439612.denisrudnei.now.sh/) um endereço com o código funcionando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mutation só pode retornar algo no formato que foi definido dentro do teu schema, quando você esbarrar num erro, o retorno vai ser nulo e junto a ele uma listagem de erros que ocorreram, vai ter o seguinte formato:

```
{
  "data": {
    "sacar": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Saldo Insuficiente",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "sacar"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Para que o graphql saiba que ocorreu o erro tu precisa deixar o erro subir:

```
const Conta = require("./Conta");
let newSaldo;

module.exports = {
    Query: {
        contas: () => Conta.find(),
        conta: (root, {
            numero
        }) => Conta.findOne({
            numero
        }),
    },

    Mutation: {
        createConta: (root, {
            numero,
            saldo,
            cliente
        }) => Conta.create({
            numero,
            saldo,
            cliente
        }),

        depositar: (root, {
                numero,
                valor
            }) => Conta.findOne({
                numero
            })
            .then(() => Conta.updateOne({
                numero
            }, {
                $inc: {
                    saldo: valor
                }
            }))
            .then(() => Conta.findOne({
                numero
            })),

        sacar: (root, {
                numero,
                valor
            }) => Conta.findOne({
                numero
            })
            .then(value => {
                newSaldo = value.saldo
                if (valor > value.saldo) {
                    throw new Error("Saldo Insuficiente")
                } else {
                    newSaldo = value.saldo - valor
                }
            })
            .then(() => Conta.updateOne({
                numero
            }, {
                $set: {
                    saldo: newSaldo
                }
            }))
            .then(() => Conta.findOne({
                numero
            }))
    },
}
```

Remover o `catch` já é suficiente, [aqui](https://439612.denisrudnei.now.sh/) um exemplo funcional, [aqui](https://gitlab.com/denisrudnei/439612) o código fonte para referência

Obs.: Não implementei a parte do banco, o exemplo funciona com a seguinte mutation:

```
mutation {
  sacar(numero: 100, valor: 100) {
    saldo
  }
}
```

---

```
mutation {
  sacar(numero: 100, valor: 101) {
    saldo
  }
}
```

Comment: Dessa forma me atendeu corretamente. Obrigado!